# Staff Wages in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I'm Learning Databases and I have a question regarding queries:

How can I workout Average Wage including Total Wage and Wage Difference?

My table is as follows:

```
Staff: staffNo(PK), staffSalary
```

The query that I have written is

```
SELECT staffNo, staffSalary,staffSalary - ( 
SELECT AVG( staffSalary ) 
FROM Staff ) AS salDiff
FROM Staff
WHERE staffSalary > ( 
SELECT AVG( staffSalary ) 
FROM Staff )
```

This query only gives me the Average Salary difference and Staff Actual Salary, how can i find out the actual Salary Average for every column of data i have? 
Also is it possible to use joins in this example?

Comment: _every column_ - you only have the columns you're working on. Is there more to this table?

Comment: your query seems fine. Or do you have multiple staffSalary for each staffNo?

Comment: Yes, StaffName, StaffPosition, StaffAddress, StaffEmailAddress

Comment: I need to find the Average Salary for each staff whoms Salary is greater than Average

Comment: do another OUTER select on what you already have maybe?

Comment: How can i accomplish that? can i not use Joins to do so?

Comment: see my answer and see if that's what you want. You said "average salary for each staff whoms salary is greater than average"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is one row per employee, here is what I believe you are asking for (for all employees making above average):

```
select staffNo,
(Select avg(staffsalary) from staff) as avgSalary,
(select staffSalary from staff where staffNo = S.StaffNo) as Salary,
(Select staffSalary - (select avg(staffSalary) from staff) from staff where staffNo = S.staffNo ) as salDiff
from staff S
where staffSalary > (Select avg(staffSalary) from staff)
```

Not sure why you need a join... unless you want to see salaries from all users, in which case you can simply remove the where clause and it will show you all staff members.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT staffNo, staffSalary,staffSalary - (SELECT AVG(staffSalary) FROM Staff ) AS salDiff,
                        (SELECT AVG(staffSalary) FROM Staff
                         WHERE staffSalary > (SELECT AVG(staffSalary) FROM Staff )) as avSalForStaffGreaterThanAverageSal
FROM Staff
WHERE staffSalary > (SELECT AVG(staffSalary) FROM Staff )
```

Comment: This query is giving the Same Average Salary for every Employee?

Comment: because it's an average. What are you expecting?

Comment: is there a case where a staffNo can have multiple staffSalary?

Comment: why don't you sqlFiddle.com your data and show your desired output?

Comment: A staffNo cant have multiple Salary but StaffNo Salary can vary from other StaffNo salaries, I think I was confused on AVG Command, Average Salary for all the StaffNo will be the same.. I was thinking that each StaffNo will have a different Average Salary.